# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > at index 4 android error

Tags: java, android, gradle

Hi I try to debug an andoid application using android studio, but I got this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> at index 4
```

and here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kevarystudio.projectName.projectName"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"
```